GT mtb unknown model, please help
enter image description hereHey Everyone I have bought a GT bicycle it’s a 21” frame I’m assuming mid 90s. crmo frame but no stickers to identify what year or model GT mtb it is. Stamped under BB
LY 9512. Forest green paint color tange chrome forks 1 1/8” Shimano Altus canti brakes. Can anyone please help me identify which GT mtb I have here?

Please add a photo with [edit]        Does it have the "triple triangle" design where the seat stays meet the top tube in front of the seat tube ?

Yes it does havre triple triangle design, let me see if I can upload a pic or a couple

Plug those handlebar holes, they are dangerous.

I see some decals/stickers on the seat tube - can you have a closer read of any of those for more clues?

What is the tyre size ?

26x1.75 tires on Araya 700 wheelset. They are V brakes it looks like. Gripshift shifters although those could have been changed throughout the years. Shimano headset that looks to be original. 21 speed Shimano groupset, says 4130 crmo seat tube

Those are cantilever brakes. GT was using them on some bikes to 1998 and maybe later.

It is not a high spec bike: don't get too hung up on the exact details. It looks like it has its original kit too. But it is worth putting new grips on and riding.

I can confirm that's a common GT frame style from the 90's.  The exact model will require a lot of checking through image searches like https://www.google.com/search?sca_upv=1&sca_upv=1&q=gt+triple+triangle+MTB+90%27s&udm=2&biw=2160&bih=1139&dpr=1.75

Its not a Zaskar - there is no fillet under the top tube behind the head tube
Not an Agressor - frame tube sizes are wrong
Noticably there are braze-on mounts for a rear rack, which eliminates Talera

Could be:

Avalanche like https://bikepacking.com/news/readers-rig-christophs-1991-gt-avalanche/
Timberline like in What are the advantages (or dis-) of the GT triple triangle frame?
Tequestra as per https://www.mtbr.com/threads/my-90s-gt-triple-triangle-xc-hardtail-gravel-thing-build.1203708/

I notice it has the branding of GT but nothing else, which implies it might be a Psyclone in 1991.  However that was early, and rack mount braze on might or might not be standard on that.
I found several sources claiming that GT used cantilever brakes like yours up till around 1993 on MTBs when they changed to V Brakes.

The fly in the ointment here is that your bike appears to have 700c wheels, not 26"   This would put it more in the field of "commuter" not MTB.
GT used the triple triangle design even on road bike frames, so its not uncommon from that era.
One possibility is the GT Passage which had 622mm wheels.

Good luck with your search, and do please add an answer of your own when you find more info.

I think this is a 1997 GT Vantara, which is shown in the catalogue in red but in the text says also in green for that year. Of course, we are looking at the wrong side of the bike to be certain.
https://www.retrobike.co.uk/gallery2/d/10529-2/1997.pdf
This bike is not a mountain bike but a "hybrid", the mtb components on a frame with 700c wheels.
GT made many variants on the same or similar frames over many years. They are good bikes if you like that sort of thing.
